# Time logging system that allows 100+ employees to assign their time to projects

Tags: web-apps, project-management, time-management, saas, human-resources

[Here's a system that we'll be checking out for now.](https://www.timecockpit.com/tour/activity-tracking) We're looking for a system that provides the following features:

- Track work times
- Track project times
- Export data to CSV (for usage in SAP)
- SAAS
- Web frontend (desktop/mobile or app)
- Complies to GDPR (Ideally hosted in Europe)
- Optionally import project data from SAP

User count: 100-110

The example in the link at the start of this post seemingly covers a lot of these use cases, however it's a bit on the steep end with 10000€ for our user count. Do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: Funnily, all companies I have worked for until now, have implemented this themselves (all companies were software development related). Two of the companies have even implemented it twice...

Comment: You might want to give https://clockify.me/self-hosted-time-tracking-software a try. Many big companies use it. If you want SaaS, it might even be free.

Comment: Will bring it up as an option, thanks!

Comment: Do you just want hours per day per project, or start/stop times? Can you not get this data from your issue tracking software, like Jira. etc? [Free, self-hosted alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/jira/?license=free&platform=self-hosted)

Comment: If you can self-host, I can recommend a couple of options. Let me know since old question now.